# Failure when using ILASM to compile IL to EXE

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, exe, il, ilasm

I've spent hours trying to figure out what is wrong. I know the program is functional, as I tested by debugging the .il in MonoDevelop, however I can't compile through that. This is the log from the command prompt:

http://pastebin.com/NYWAbrUV

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Failed to write output file, error code=0x80070005

0x80070005 is an access denied error. You either don't have the rights to create a file into the directory, or you're trying to overwrite a file which is opened somewhere else.

Comment: I realize this comment is a *few* months too late, but I did manage to figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this trying to compile an example from a book. What eventually worked for me was specifying the full path to the output parameter.

```
ilasm c:\folder\codefile.il /output=c:\folder\outfile.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for everyone else who has this problem *due to the usage of a key-file for signing*:

The file which can not be accessed due to `0x80070005` does not have to be the `.il`-file.
Like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678639/3905529) answer I had to give permissions of my user to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`.